# How does MongoDB sort/compare objects

Tags: mongodb

Couldn't find any clear documentation on how does MongoDB compare/sort complex objects. I've tried some examples and found out property order does matter and property names also matter
Examples:-

Order matter
`{“name”: {“first”: “A”, “last”: “B”}} != {“name”: {“last”: “B”, “first”: “A”}}`

Values matter
`{“name”: {“first”: “A”}} < {“name”: {“first”: “B”}}`

property names matter
`{“name”: {“**f**irst”: “A”}} < {“name”: {“**g**irst”: “A”}}`

So wondering how exactly does that work, I'm sure stuff like missing properties would also affect this.

Comment: How did you come to the point of using equality operators with json documents?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort on embedded object fields like `name`, the sort comparisons are done using at the binary representation (BSON object) level, which isn't very useful.

What you typically want to do instead is identity the specific fields within those objects using dot notation, putting them in the order you want:

```
// Sort on last name, and then first name
db.test.find().sort({'name.last': 1, 'name.first': 1})
```